# How numpy comparison works

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to this field, this script is used to get 80% of data randomly into training list, and the rest 20% in testing list. This script works, but I have a few questions about why it works.
If len(data) is 1000, then randn(1000) will generate 1000 random number with normal distribution. What I do not understand are:
1)I test myself such as [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]<5 I got an error,because the left operator is a list.But why check=a<0.8 legal, a should be a list of 1000 elements?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
data = pd.read_csv('E:/Personal/Learning/Datasets/Book/Customer ChurnModel.txt')
len(data)
a=np.random.randn(len(data))
check=a<0.8
training=data[check]
testing=data[~check]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy arrays overload the comparison operators to perform the operation per-element, not per container.

In other words,

```
check=a<0.8
```

will create a new NumPy array `check` of the same length as `a` such that:

```
check[i] = a[i] < 0.8
```

Comment: so you are saying a is not a standard list?

Comment: Yes, the return type of np.random.randn is numpy.ndarray, not list.

Comment: That's right, NumPy arrays are a different type from standard Python lists. Generally NumPy operations can work with both, but there is often a performance cost to use a Python list.

Answer (score 0):

Well check variable works as a boolean object and in the code the line for that is only an assignation. 
In other hand, the comparison with two objects have to be the same type.
type([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) --> 'list' object
type(5) --> 'int' object

Answer (score 0):

In contrast with the built-in types such as `list`, `numpy` arrays take advantage of the Python rich comparison system by overriding the comparison operators. This is in order to allow comparison with atomic types, numpy-array-like types, etc. The rich comparison operators return new arrays (rather than just a `True` or `False`).

Anyone can write a class that [does custom comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) like `numpy` arrays.

Helpful tip: if you use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), you only have to [provide two methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customization), such as, `__eq__` and `__lt__`:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Mine:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        ...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        ...
```

The remaining methods are sort-of automatically intuited when you provide correct behavior for these two. However in practice, to get a class working the way you want, one will often find it is needed to customize the behaviors of the other rich comparison methods: `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__le__`, and `__ge__`.